# two media player played at once

Tags: android, audio

i create an app, and in one layout (just call it layout A), i play the media player, then when i went to another layout (just call it Layout B), i want the sound from the Layout A is continue playing in Layout B, and when i went back to the Layout A, i also want the media player is still continuing the music that was played before.

In Layout A, i set this code in onCreate:

```
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound); 
    if(!isMuted())
    {
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.start();
    }

...

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
            stop=1;
            startActivity(intent);          
        }
    });
```

And this code:

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (stop!=1)
    {
        //stop=1 if i go to another layout, for example when i want to go to Layout B
        //if the device is automatically locked, i want the media player is paused and it resumed when i unlock the device, so i use stop!=1 to know whether the sound should be paused or not
        player.pause();
        length = player.getCurrentPosition();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if(!isMuted())
    {
        //isMuted is method to know whether the sound is muted or not, if it isn't muted, then the sound is resumed
        player.seekTo(length);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.start();
    }
}
```

In layout B, i used this code in onCreate:

```
 player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
 ....
```

And this code:

```
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    player.pause();
    length = player.getCurrentPosition();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if(!isMuted())
    {
        if(player.isPlaying())
        {

        }
        else
        {
            player.seekTo(length);
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.start();
        }
    }
}
```

But this is the problem.

1. When i went to Layout B, the Media Player from Layout A and Media Player from Layout B is played in the same time, so the sound is played simultaneously at one time.
2. When i went back to the Layout A, the Media Player in Layout B is stopped and the Media Player in Layout A is stopped and played from the beginning again, it didn't continue the Media Player that was played before.
3. When the device is locked, the media player is still played although i have used the indicator whether is should be paused or not. Any correction to the code?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use a Service to play and pause/stop your music. It is not recommended to use Activity to handle music that way. You can start a Service and then play music in it. Services run in background and don't get destroyed automatically too often as compared to Activity. Here's a sample app code that does similar to what you need [media player sound continue in all activities](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/60/servicesdemo_using_android_services)

Answer (score 0):

In Activity MediaPlayer can play far.
You should use Service to play MediaPlayer and control from anywhere in application.
I used this tutorial.
https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/60/servicesdemo_using_android_service